# Wordpress output posts with category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs, categories

I have loop which outputs last 3 posts:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            /////////insert smth
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to make sure that post category is equal to "vakancy", can i filter only for posts only with this category or i will have to use (if!=) ?

Comment: Have you read the docs for get_posts() yet? https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts - `category_name` is an option shown right at the start...

Answer (score 1):

Sure its easy: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category_name' => 'vakancy' );
    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            /////////insert smth
<?php endforeach; ?>
```